# Windows 7 Open File Security Warning

Tags: windows-7, security-warning

I downloaded something and now, it is show this open file security warning. I have searched but I have only found how to disable security warnings globally.

I only want to say NO forever to this warning, but it keeps showing up whenever Windows starts.

The "Name" and "From" are:

"C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Temp/Windows-Update.exe"

I cannot even find that folder and file!

I don't really know what was downloaded, I am helping someone else. (I am not a Windows user, so I am very lost here)

Comment: please provide us with details of what you downloaded and the security message you are receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean a warning like this?

[image: 1]

If so, do *not* unblock or allow this! From the file name and location, it looks very much to be a trojan/malware of some sort. I would highly recommend that you download and run a copy of [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security-essentials-download) or any other *good* anti-virus/anti-malware program on that machine immediately.

Comment: If MSE doesn't find and remove the malware/error then take a look at [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org). Failing that your next step would be to run `msconfig` and remove the startup entry for that file (this will remove the startup, not the actual file from your system).

Comment: @HaydnWVN: Thanks, I completely forgot to mention MBAM.

Comment: MBAM is just the next step; obviously my comment could contain much more information about identifying the infection and then removing it, but it would be easier to contain the information in an answer. Of course there are many of these answers already on the site for other questions regarding malware.

Answer (score -1):

That is not a legitimate file. attempt to permanently delete it, and then update your antivirus software and do a full scan of your system.

Comment: How exactly did you determine the file is malicious exactly.  Seems like this should have been a comment since this doesn't answer the author's question.

Comment: between its name and path, it is clearly an imposter malware using a name that the author believes will make people think it is legitimate. windows update would never run from that path and includes a digitial signature that would prevent the warning in question from displaying. Deleting the file is the easiest way to make the warning go away forever as the op requested.

Comment: I don't disagree its likely malware, I just don't agree, this should single statement should be an answer.  Furthermore just removing the file won't solve the real problem the author has, if he does that, he will just get a "cannot find file" error.